# Como hago que este codigo abra una nueva pagina?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una seccion XXX en mi pagina web, y quisiera que cuando el usuario toque el banner para ir a esa seccion, salga una ventana emergente que pregunte si tiene la edad para ingresar, pero solo logre esto, y aunque sale la ventana emergente, no me abre la pagina:

```
<img src="https://od.lk/s/MzNfMTY5NjQxNzJf/XXX.png" width=auto height="100" onclick="return confirm('¿Tienes 18+?')" href="https://www.google.com/"> <script> var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP"); el_up.innerHTML = "Debes ser mayor de edad para entrar a esta sección."; </script>
```

Comment: No, ese es el unico, solo quiero q me salga el mensaje de confirmacion al tocar la imagne del banner, y me reedirija a otra pagina, es todo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algunas observaciones:

- El utilizar `confirm` solo te da como posibles resultados: `true` o `false` dependiendo que presione el usuario
- En función de ello con un condicional tú deberás establecer la lógica de lo que ocurrirá en cualquiera de los 2 casos
- A la etiqueta que contiene tu banner, que puede ser una `img` debes recuperarla y darle un listener en su evento `click` para evaluar cuando el usuario ejecuta dicha acción sobre el
- Para abrir una nueva página si el `confirm` es verdadero utilizaremos el método `open` del objeto `window` donde le pasamos 2 argumentos:

  - URL a la cual vamos a apuntar
  - Indicar si el recurso se cargará en la pestaña actual o abriremos una nueva

Para este ejemplo he simulado el banner con una etiqueta `article` sobre la cual puedes dar click y evaluar el comportamiento que descrito

```html
    <style>
      .banner {
        color: white;
        background-color: crimson;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <article class="banner">
      Ir a la sección prohibida
    </article>
    <script>
      let banner = document.querySelector('.banner')
      
      banner.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let eleccion = confirm('¿Tienes mas de 18?')
        
        if (!eleccion) {
          console.log('No tienes edad para esto');
        } else {
          window.open('https://es.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
        }
          
      })
    </script>
```

Como recomendación: No coloques la lógica dentro de tus etiquetas HTML, eso lo hace muy complicado de manejar y mantener, sobre todo si la lógica de tu desarrollo se debe incrementar.

- Para que conozcas mas del comportamiento de `confirm` te recomiendo [leas este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero lo que necesitaba era mas como esto:

<img class="banner" src="https://od.lk/s/MzNfMTY5NjQxNzJf/XXX.png" width=300px" height=auto>

    <script>
      let banner = document.querySelector('.banner')
      
      banner.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let eleccion = confirm('¿Tienes mas de 18?')
        
        if (!eleccion) {
          console.log('No tienes edad para esto');
        } else {
          window.open('https://es.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
        }
          
      })
    </script>